# How can I make optional matches?

Tags: regex, autoit

The following is written in AutoIt Script, but the question is about Regular Expressions in general.

```
Func GetNthValueFromStatubar($n)
    ; Get status text as string.
    $Status = StatusbarGetText($MainWindowTitle)
    ; Find value based on N.
    If $n = 1 Then
        $Result = StringRegExp( $Status, "[A-Za-z: ]+\$([A-Z0-9]+)", 1 )
    ElseIf $n = 2 Then
        $Result = StringRegExp( $Status, "[A-Za-z: ]+\$([A-Z0-9]+)[\s]*[A-Za-z: ]+\$([A-Z0-9]+)", 1 )
    ElseIf $n = 3 Then
        $Result = StringRegExp( $Status, "[A-Za-z: ]+\$([A-Z0-9]+)[\s]*[A-Za-z: ]+\$([A-Z0-9]+)[\s]*[A-Za-z: ]+\$([A-Z0-9]+)", 1 )
    EndIf
    Return $Result[$n - 1]
EndFunc
```

I would like to eliminate the if-statements and write only a single regular expression check. To do this, I think that the 2nd and 3rd matches are going to have to be optional.

I am aware that I can make characters optional by using an asterisk (`*`) instead of a plus (`+`). However this does not seem to work when used in combination with curvey braces `()`.

In other words, I think this should work, but it doesn't. It returns zero results, except when `N = 3`:

`[A-Za-z: ]+\$([A-Z0-9]+)[\s]*[A-Za-z: ]*\$([A-Z0-9]*)[\s]*[A-Za-z: ]*\$([A-Z0-9]*)`

How can I make the 2nd and 3rd matches, the parts within `()`, optional so that one check can be used regardless of whether the string contains 1, 2, or 3 matches?

Comment: You may want to provide some examples of what these regular expressions are supposed to be matching.

Comment: You may try something like `a((b)?(c)?)?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the quantifier `?`, it means 0 or 1. It is the short form of `{0,1}`. Your regex would then look like this:

```
[A-Za-z: ]+\$([A-Z0-9]+)([\s]*[A-Za-z: ]+\$([A-Z0-9]+))?([\s]*[A-Za-z: ]+\$([A-Z0-9]+))?
```

But since the optional expression is the same, you can say match that part 0, 1 or 2 times like this:

```
[A-Za-z: ]+\$([A-Z0-9]+)([\s]*[A-Za-z: ]+\$([A-Z0-9]+)){0,2}
```

The quantifier `{0,2}` works this way `{min,max}`, where `min` defines the minimum amount of required repetitions and `max` the maximum.
You can also omit the `max` part `{1,}` means it would match at least one. This is the long version of `+`.

Comment: Works perfectly thank you. Didn't realize that you could nest `()` within `()` and only the innermost one would be considered the "match".

Answer (score 1):

`(rexex1)(optional regex1)?(optional regex2)?`

Working for you?

Actually you may be using `*` instead of `?` but `*` may match more than one occurrence and as far as I am reading you want one or zero matches instead. You can nest braces if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

try this approach:

```
Func GetNthValueFromStatubar($n)

    ; Get status text as string.    
    $Status = StatusbarGetText($MainWindowTitle)

    ;define regex
    $reg = "[A-Za-z: ]+\$([A-Z0-9]+)";

    ; Find value based on N.
    for($i=2; $i<=$n; $i++)
    {
       $reg .= "[\s]*".$reg; 
    }
    $Result = StringRegExp($Status, $reg, 1)

    Return $Result[$n - 1]
EndFunc
```